# Install newer version of octomap on Groovy?

Tags: octomap, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am currently on Groovy and cannot upgrade due to limitations of our group. However, I would like to get a newer version of Octomap package on Groovy, how would I do that?

The package website states "This means that you compile against OctoMap without requiring any ROS-specific build tools or catkin macros (in fact, they won't work)." What does this mean?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196121/install-newer-version-of-octomap-on-groovy?/) by [silentwf](https://answers.ros.org/users/19240/silentwf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2014-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It means that octomap is a standalone package (i.e. ROS agnostic). You can include that in your project as any other cmake package.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0